# Can't create/send iMessage in my extension on any view except the initial view

Tags: swift, xcode-storyboard, imessage, imessage-extension

I'm currently working on an iMessage app which has the users sign in on storyboard view 1 and then allows them to generate/send a message on storyboard view 2. After many attempts, I'm finding that the MSMessage portion of the code just doesn't execute on any view except view 1 - the initial view controller.
I'm sure this is a simple fix but I honestly just can't find out why. Any help would be appreciated.

Message generation/send code:

```
@IBAction func Testing(_ sender: Any) {
        let layout = MSMessageTemplateLayout()
        layout.caption = "Hello World"
        let message = MSMessage()
        message.layout = layout
        activeConversation?.insert(message, completionHandler: nil)
    }
```

Comment: if you want to help in your code then please show the code

Comment: It's not the code I'm having issues with as it works perfectly fine on the initial view controller. Just need help to figure out why it doesn't work on any other views.

Comment: then it must be the problem of your code if it is not working